# Access and disable dynamically created fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dynamic form (add form fields by press button "Hinzufügen").

But i need some functions and dosent get along with it :-(

The dynamic creation works fine also post the form as array works fine.

But now i need to disable some fields when new fields are created but i dont find the selectors to deal with it ...

What I want to do:

When a new fields are created all the "von" `(data[?][von])` and the "bis" `(data[?][bis])` fields from the fields before should be disabled.

On the new fields the "von" field should contain the data from the last "bis" field and should also be disabled.

Here is the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MaxInputs       = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID
    var submit1       = $("#submit"); 

    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
    var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

    $(submit1).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
    {
        $("#abser").submit(); 
    });

    $(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
    {
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#3391B0;"><label><font color="#FFFFFF">Weg:</font></label></div><div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#EDF8FE"><p><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="formtable" ><tr class="tablebg"><td ><label class="inline">Von:</label><input name="data['+ FieldCount +'][von]" type="text"   class="text nextto" /></td><td><label class="inline">Bis:</label><input name="data['+ FieldCount +'][bis]" type="text" class="text nextto" /></td></tr></table></p><p><label class="inline" for="art">Art:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="data['+ FieldCount +'][art]" class="text nextto"><option value="Ortsaugenschein">Ortsaugenschein</option></select></p><p><label class="inline">Ort:</label><input name="data['+ FieldCount +'][ort]" type="text" class="text inline" /></p><p><label class="inline">Detail:</label></br><textarea name="data['+ FieldCount +'][detail]"></textarea></p></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
        }
        return false;
    }) 
});
```

```
<center><h6>Absenz erfassen</h6></center>
<div class="grid_12">
    <div class="grid_3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="grid_6">
        <form id="abser" action="addon/absdb/testpost.php"  method="post">
            <label class="inline">Datum:</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="datum" id="dtp_input2" value="" />
            <div id="InputsWrapper">
                <div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#3391B0;">
                    <label><font color="#FFFFFF">Weg:</font></label>
                </div>
                <div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#EDF8FE">
                    <p>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="formtable" >
                            <tr class="tablebg">
                                <td>
                                    <label class="inline">Von:</label><input name="data[1][von]" type="text"   class="text nextto" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label class="inline">Bis:</label><input name="data[1][bis]" type="text" class="text nextto" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label class="inline" for="art">Art:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select name="data[1][art]" class="text nextto">
                            <option value="Ortsaugenschein">Ortsaugenschein</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label class="inline">Ort:</label>
                        <input name="data[1][ort]" type="text" class="text inline" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label class="inline">Detail:</label>
                        </br>
                        <textarea name="data[1][detail]"></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" id="AddMoreFileBox" value="Hinzufügen" />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Speichern" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `.removeclass` element? Also `English` language, please what is `Hinzufügen`?

Comment: Sorry i dosent removed it in this view the user cant remove the fields so the .removeclass is not in use ... in a other you can remove the created fields by pressing the .removeclass button (X next the created fields) ...

Comment: You can select the [von] fields like $('input[name$="[von]"]'). Similarly for [bis] $('input[name$="[bis]"]') . "name$" means the attribute ending with the value specified. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks !!! Now i know to select the fields :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works as described :-)

THANKS for helping !!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID
var submit1       = $("#submit");  
var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

 $(submit1).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
 {
    $("#abser").submit(); 
 });

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
 {
     $('input[name$="[von]"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     $('input[name$="[bis]"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

         if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
         {
             FieldCount++; //text box added increment
             //add input box
             var lastfield = FieldCount-1;
             var lasttime = $('input[name$="['+ lastfield +'][bis]"]').val();
             $(InputsWrapper).append('<div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#3391B0;"><label><font color="#FFFFFF">Weg:</font></label></div><div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#EDF8FE"><p><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="formtable" ><tr class="tablebg"><td ><label class="inline">Von:</label><input name="data['+ FieldCount +'][von]" type="text" value="'+ lasttime +'"  disabled="disabled"  class="text nextto" /></td><td><label class="inline">Bis:</label><input name="data['+ FieldCount +'][bis]" type="text" class="text nextto" /></td></tr></table></p><p><label class="inline" for="art">Art:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="data['+ FieldCount +'][art]" class="text nextto"><option value="Ortsaugenschein">Ortsaugenschein</option></select></p><p><label class="inline">Ort:</label><input name="data['+ FieldCount +'][ort]" type="text" class="text inline" /></p><p><label class="inline">Detail:</label></br><textarea name="data['+ FieldCount +'][detail]"></textarea></p></div>');
             x++; //text box increment
         }

 return false;

 });

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
         if( x > 1 ) {
                 $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                 x--; //decrement textbox
         }
 return false;
 }) 
});
```

---

```
<center><h6>Absenz erfassen</h6></center>



<div class="grid_12">
<div class="grid_3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="grid_6">

<form id="abser" action="addon/absdb/testpost.php"  method="post">


<label class="inline">Datum:</label>

<div class="controls input-append date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
<input size="16" type="text" value=""  readonly>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="datum" id="dtp_input2" value="" />

<div id="InputsWrapper">

<div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#3391B0;"><label><font color="#FFFFFF">Weg:</font></label>

</div><div style="border: 1px solid silver; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#EDF8FE"><p><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="formtable" ><tr class="tablebg"><td >

<label class="inline">Von:</label><input name="data[1][von]" type="text"   class="text nextto" />


</td><td>

<label class="inline">Bis:</label><input name="data[1][bis]" type="text" class="text nextto" />

</td></tr></table></p><p>

<label class="inline" for="art">Art:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="data[1][art]" class="text nextto">

<option value="Ortsaugenschein">Ortsaugenschein</option></select>

</p><p>

<label class="inline">Ort:</label><input name="data[1][ort]" type="text" class="text inline" />

</p><p>

<label class="inline">Detail:</label></br><textarea name="data[1][detail]"></textarea>

</p></div>


</div>

<p>

<input type="submit" class="submit" id="AddMoreFileBox" value="Hinzufügen" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Speichern" />
</p>
</form>

</div>

<div class="grid_3">
&nbsp;
</div>

</div>
```